# How to find out the missing day (eg. 2018-08) from variable in R

Tags: r

How to find out the missing day (eg. 2018-08) from variable in R. And i need to create a var with the following condition. if missing, the first of the month (eg. 2018-08-**01**) will be used unless this is before the start date of study treatment; in this case the study treatment start date will be used.

Unique ID    Start date     Study treatment Start date

1            2018-12-29       2018-12-29
2            2018-08          2018-09-29
3            2018-09-25       2018-09-24
4            2018-09          2018-08-24
5            2018-09-25       2018-09-28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test for number of characters in `Start_date`, if they are less than 10 paste the date (01) and convert it into Date. You can then find minimum of the two dates using `pmin`.

```
#Get index where there are missing dates for `Start_date`
inds <- nchar(df$Start_date) < 10
#Add date (01) to it 
df$Start_date[inds] <- paste0(df$Start_date[inds], '-01')
#Convert to date class
df$Start_date <- as.Date(df$Start_date)
df$Study_treatment <- as.Date(df$Study_treatment)
#Replace with minimum value between Start_date and Study_treatment
df$Start_date[inds] <- pmin(df$Start_date[inds], df$Study_treatment[inds])
df
#  Unique_ID Start_date Study_treatment
#1         1 2018-12-29      2018-12-29
#2         2 2018-08-01      2018-09-29
#3         3 2018-09-25      2018-09-24
#4         4 2018-08-24      2018-08-24
#5         5 2018-09-25      2018-09-28
```

Comment: Thank you so much. i want to compare only the replaced one with the study treatment date not all the observation. so in dis case i assume i cannot use pmin!!!

Comment: @Jannet You can still use `pmin` only on replaced dates. See updated answer.